# Inserting a cell in excel based on cell value

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

I am working on exporting CSVs of large groups from an active directory environment.  Many of these groups have extensive nesting and I need to insert cells so that the worksheet is human readable.

For example my worksheet looks like this:
WS Example

> Int User  Path
>
> 0              User1     CN
>
> 0              User2     CN
>
> 1          User3     CN
>
> 1          User4     CN
>
> 0          User5     CN
>
> 1          User6     CN
>
> 2          User7     CN

I am looking for help adapting a VBA script that reads the integer value from the first column and inserts the corresponding number of cells to the left of the column for that particular row.  The constraint is that the list cannot change the order of the rows so as to preserve the nested structure.

Here is what I have in VBA so far

```
Sub test()
Dim d As Integer
d = Range("A:A").End(xlDown).row
Dim c As Range
  For i = d To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 1).Value Like "1" Then
  Rows(Cells(i, 1).Column).Insert shift:=xlShiftRight
   End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Currently this snippet counts the number of 1's from the column and inserts a new row at the top of the list.  I believe the error in my logic is within the If statement and once I have that ironed out I know I can expand that with an ElseIf to address the rest of the values.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it. The issue looks like it's within the line `Rows(Cells(i, 1).Column).Insert shift:=xlShiftRight`. If you break that down, it computes as follows:

`Cells(i,1).Column` which equals 1, since the column of `.Cells(i,1)` is 1.
`Rows(1)` the `1` comes from the above. So `Rows(1)` is 1.
`Rows(1).Insert` inserts above row 1, regardless of what you specify for shift.

```
Sub test()
Dim d As Integer
d = Range("A:A").End(xlDown).row
Dim c As Range
  For i = d To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 1).Value Like "1" Then
       Cells(i, 1).Insert shift:=xlToRight
   End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I think this only shifts one column to the right... I think the question asks for the number of columns shifted to be variable...

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
Sub test()
Dim d As Integer
d = Range("A:A").End(xlDown).Row
Dim c As Range
  For i = d To 1 Step -1
    aMove = Val(Cells(i, 1))
    If aMove > 0 Then
    Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, aMove)).Insert shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
   End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few ways to do this, but by using the number in columnA to define the amount of cells to insert you can do a second loop like so:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim x, d, i As Integer
With ActiveSheet
d = .Range("A:A").End(xlDown).Row
    For x = 2 To d
    i = .Cells(x, 1).Value
        For a = 1 To i
            .Cells(x, 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Next a
    Next x
End With
End Sub
```